# Does it make any sense to install CUDA drivers unde Wine?

Tags: wine

I am using a graphics-heavy application under Wine, and I constantly get cuda errors (cudaErrorInsufficientDriver).

Does it make any sense to install Nvidia GPU drivers under Wine?